# Table TH not displaying correctly after onchange evernt fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

So I'm trying to hide the *Company Name* `<th>` column when the employee drop down is selected.

I have this jQuery function that I've been trying to figure out for sometime now and cant seem to get it working. I've tried to walk though script with FF debugger but nothing happens, with no errors. Im kind of lost on where to take it from here.

**DropDown**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.DropDownList("SearchStatus", new SelectList(ViewBag.SearchStatusList, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.SelectedItem), new { @class = "form-control",  @onchange = "form.submit();" })
}
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#SearchStatus").on("change", function () {
    if ($("#SearchStatus option:selected").val() == 0) {
        $("#hidden_div").hide();
    } else {
        $("#hidden_div").show();
    }
});
```

**VIEW**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Login.Models.EditProfile>

@using PagedList.Mvc;


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Pending Accounts";
}

 <link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


<style>
... deleted CSS that was here
</style>


 <h2>Pending Accounts</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.DropDownList("SearchStatus", new  SelectList(ViewBag.SearchStatusList, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.SelectedItem), new { @class = "form-control",  @onchange = "form.submit();" })
 }
 <br />

  <table class="table grid">
   <tr>
    <th>
        <b>Options</b>
    </th>

    <th>
        First Name:
    </th>
    <th>
        Last Name:
    </th>

    <th>
        Email:
    </th>
    <th>
        Phone Number:
    </th>

    <th id="hidden_div" style="display: none;">       
            Company Name:
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.ToList())
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" id="bootstrap-ok" class="btn btn-default btn-sm icon-success">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok "></span>
                </button>

                <button type="button" id="bootstrap-danger" class="btn btn-default btn-sm icon-danger">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhoneNumber)
        </td>
        @if (item.CompanyName != null)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.CompanyName)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
    }
 </table>

<br />
 Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of          @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("PendingAccounts", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
 {
using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Logout</a>
    }
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#SearchStatus").on("change", function () {
    if ($("#SearchStatus option:selected").val() == 0) {
        $("#hidden_div").hide();
    } else {
        $("#hidden_div").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your submitting your form when you select an option (a terrible idea for many reasons) so you show/hide the `<div>` but then immediately submit and go to a new page. You need to show/hide it when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value of the dropdown by using $(yourDropdown).val() and not selecting the options. So try this:

```
$("#SearchStatus").on("change", function () {
    if ($("#SearchStatus").val() == 0) {
        $("#hidden_div").hide();
    } else {
        $("#hidden_div").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: If you accept in the event to the handler then `e.target.value` would get you the value without a dom lookup.  Or `this.value`

Comment: you can youse e.target.value only if you pass "e" to the callback and if the dropdown has custom style (not native) you'll get a problem because you may select another element. this.value will be ok in the case of jquery

Comment: I mentioned that the event would have to be passed in.  Can you elaborate on the issue you think doing it with the event would impose?  I don't understand that part.